# What is the parameter of the power source that satisfies the inrush current of the load?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

Power supplies (more specifically, the SMPS') have voltage and current rating on its label. However, the inrush current supplement capability will depend from supply to supply.

- What is the unit of inrush current?

  - Is it Joules?
  - Is it Coulombs?
  - Is it Amperes along with the duration (which is Coulombs actually, with split parameters)?
- How can we identify (thus test) the inrush current provision of a power supply?

Comment: None it's plain ordinary amps.

Comment: If it needs to be sustained for a time period, then specify that: x current peak (surge) for y seconds.

Comment: I am not sure you are using the right term here. In-rush current is the current absorbed by the converter when you cold-plug it in an ac outlet. It is expressed in amperes and must be within a certain level for domestic or industrial usage. What you seem to refer to is peak power, meaning the maximum power a converter can deliver - for instance to sustain the in-rush current of a load like a capacitor bank or a motor - before the protection trips or the converter smokes. See here for more data https://www.emea.lambda.tdk.com/uk/KB/Understanding-peak-power.pdf

Comment: @VerbalKint Yes, exactly: "to sustain the in-rush current of a load like a capacitor bank or a motor - before the protection trips"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the unit of inrush current?

Ampere. It's a current. Typically, you'd look at *peak* current.

As you can see from that, it's not really a meaningful thing to give on its own.

> How can we identify (thus test) the inrush current provision of a power supply?

Short circuit the output. Observe the current through the short with a fast measurement device.

Really, for most applications, source impedance is more useful a measure, I'd say.

Comment: This doesn't sound right at the first glance. If a power supply would have a 10 times large capacitors on its output, then it will probably develop the same amount of current at the first moment comparing to its original, 1x capacitor variant. However, the 10x capacitor version will provide more energy to the load, which might be enough to start the load up (eg. an electric motor) and make it run its steady current. Are you sure that it doesn't have anything to do with the duration?

Comment: yes. Inrush *current* is a *current*. If you want to describe something else, do that, but it's not inrush current.

Comment: Reading my own question, it's possible to interpret the question in the way you do. I want to test the inrush current provision capability of a power supply. The underlying motivation of this question is to be able to answer the question: "Is `this` power supply able to handle the inrush current demand of `that` device." Obviously just testing the device is the way to go, but how can we order a new power supply equivalent to our current one? We need to specify its startup current capability to the manufacturer. What is that parameter's unit?

Comment: That depends on what your device looks like! A cold filament bulb has a different inrush behaviour than a microwave oven.

Comment: Exactly!? What I need to do at this point is define the startup characteristics of my device and then order a power supply that meets the startup demand. Question is this: How should I define the startup characteristics? Obviously inrush current is not sufficient because it lacks the definition of duration.

Comment: yeah, but really, only you know what your device needs. So you simply need to write that down. It's not going to be a single number with a single physical unit.